# Is anybody using Metarocket.io as a SFDC GUI?

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, git

Was trying to find a way to Find & Replace Visualforce page names in an org and this [community answer](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A7zxTSAR) lead me to MavensMate which is not supported anymore.

Then [this question](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005kNqQAI) looking for an alternative lead me to the discovery of MetaRocket.io to replace MavensMate and beyond.

The fact that it is a SFDX GUI client (working on Mac, PC and Linux) looks appealing and it ticks a lot of boxes beyond the original request but surprising that it does not look that well-known in the community hence my looking for other experiences before trying it.

Thanks a mill in advance for any feedback or alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

We use metarocket at work and absolutely love it. It's fairly new, but you are correct, it ticks all the boxes and then some. I do believe it will really take off once it becomes more known.